# Javassist CannotCompileException when trying to add values to a Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

Hi I am trying to create and fill a map of type  during the instrumentation. Previously I used a Map and it worked fine. But now I want to add any type of value into that map based on the situation. Therefore I have written the instrumentation code as follows.

```
sBuilder.append("java.util.Map/*<String,Object>*/ ");
        sBuilder.append(mapName);
        sBuilder.append("= new java.util.HashMap/*<String,Object>*/();");
        for (ParameterName parameter : insertMapList) {
            sBuilder.append(mapName);
            sBuilder.append(".put(\"");
            sBuilder.append(parameter.getKey());
            sBuilder.append("\",");
            sBuilder.append(parameter.getParameterValue());
            sBuilder.append(");");
        }
```

I have been trying to add a value as <"query_4",34>. But it is throwing following exception.

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] put(java.lang.String,int) not found in java.util.Map
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:774)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at org.wso2.das.javaagent.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassTransformer.createInsertBefore(InstrumentationClassTransformer.java:179)
    at org.wso2.das.javaagent.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassTransformer.instrumentMethod(InstrumentationClassTransformer.java:145)
    at org.wso2.das.javaagent.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassTransformer.instrumentClass(InstrumentationClassTransformer.java:138)
    at org.wso2.das.javaagent.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassTransformer.transform(InstrumentationClassTransformer.java:84)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:429)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:262)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:112)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: compile error: put(java.lang.String,int) not found in java.util.Map
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:723)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:688)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:569)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:754)
```

Why am I getting this exception. As I have understood we can add any type of value to a Object type variable. But why does it throw above exception?

Comment: Looks like you need to box the value. I don't know enough about Javassist to help you with that, but I'd definitely try to find boxing in the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Skeet mentioned in a comment above, it looks like you need to box the `int` in order to get an `Integer` (which is a subtype of `Object`). You can do that by calling `Integer.valueOf(int)`. So, I guess change this:

```
            sBuilder.append("\",");
            sBuilder.append(parameter.getParameterValue());
            sBuilder.append(");");
```

to this:

```
            sBuilder.append("\", Integer.valueOf(");
            sBuilder.append(parameter.getParameterValue());
            sBuilder.append("));");
```